# Define a one to one relationship on same model with an association model between using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using sqlalchemy, I want to define a one to one relationship between two instances of the same model linked by an association model.

Here is what I have so far:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    partner_relationship = relationship('PersonRelationship', uselist=True)
    

class PersonRelationship(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person_relationships'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    person2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    relationship_type = Column(String(50))  # Additional attribute for the relationship

    person1 = relationship('Person', foreign_keys=[person1_id], back_populates='partner_relationship')
    person2 = relationship('Person', foreign_keys=[person2_id], back_populates='partner_relationship')


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///the_database.db')
session = Session(engine)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

p1 = Person()
p2 = Person()

relationship_ = PersonRelationship(person1 = p1, person2 = p2, person1_id=p1.id, person2_id=p2.id)

session.add(p1)
session.add(p2)
session.add(relationship_)

session.commit()
```

I have been going through the sqlalchemy documentation

The closest documentation I could find to what I am looking for (I want one2one with same model):

[m2m with association model](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#combining-association-object-with-many-to-many-access-patterns)

and managed to make this work if the left and right models of the one to one cardinality are different but not if they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that define your model and relations in this way
and use `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin`:

```
class PersonRelationship(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'person_relationships'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    person2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    relationship_type = Column(String(50))  # Additional attribute for the relationship


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    partner_relationship = relationship(
        'Person',
        secondary='person_relationships',
        primaryjoin=id == PersonRelationship.person1_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == PersonRelationship.person2_id,
    )
```

Comment: I assume that you instantiate the `p1` and `p2` as I have done in my original question then instantiate the `PersonRelationship `instance as such: `relationship_ = PersonRelationship(person1_id=p1.id, person2_id=p2.id)`?

There are two issues that ensue, why does `p1.partner_relationship` return and empty list `[]`? And how can I navigate from on instance to another with either of the persons `p1`, or `p2` or the Relationship instance using the ORM type navigation?